# AWS APIGateway with Cognito Authorizer defined in OpenAPI Spec

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

**Tools**

- Terraform v0.11.14

**Setup**

- API Gateway managed by Terraform, defined using OpenAPI Spec
- Cognito Authorizer

I'm trying to specify the Authorizer for a method in my API.  I can do this using the console (it's pretty well documented):

[image: Manual Cognito Authorizer]

**Problem**

I want to be able to set this programatically using the OpenAPI spec.  The relevant documentation from AWS is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-enable-cognito-user-pool.html)

It says that you can create the Authorizer object in the OpenAPI spec by specifying:

```
securitySchemes:
  NameOfCognitoAuthorizer:
    type: apiKey
    name: Authorization
    in: header
    x-amazon-apigateway-authtype: cognito_user_pools
    x-amazon-apigateway-authorizer:
      type: cognito_user_pools
      providerARNs:
      - 'arn:aws:cognito-idp:{region}:{account_id}:userpool/{user_pool_id}'
```

This works as expected.

And then once this is done, you should be able to apply the Authorizer to a resource method as follows:

```
post:
  summary: Create a new Item
  responses:
    '200':
      description: Ok
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Item'
  security:
    - NameOfCognitoAuthorizer:
```

However, once I apply the changes and inspect the post method in the AWS console, I can see that the Authorizer has not been applied to the API method.  Can anyone see what I have done wrong?

For completeness, my API is created using terraform:

```sh
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "this" {
  name        = "MyAPI"
  body        = "${file("./api-spec.yaml")}"

  endpoint_configuration {
    types = ["REGIONAL"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same issue. Here's an example of an OpenAPI spec that works:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Sample API
  description: api description here
  version: '0.1'
paths:
  /:
    get:
      summary: Describe the endpoint
      responses:
        '200':
          description: "All good"
      security:
        - EndpointAuthorizer: ["test/read"]
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        uri: arn:aws:apigateway:{region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:{region}:{account_id}:function:{function_name}/invocations
        passthroughBehavior: "when_no_match"
        httpMethod: "POST"
        type: "aws_proxy"
components:
  securitySchemes:
    EndpointAuthorizer:
      type: apiKey
      name: Authorization
      in: header
      x-amazon-apigateway-authtype: cognito_user_pools
      x-amazon-apigateway-authorizer:
        type: cognito_user_pools
        providerARNs:
          - arn:aws:cognito-idp:{region}:{account_id}:userpool/{user_pool_id}
```

The key is the security reference on the endpoint (note `test/read` here is the scope I defined on Cognito, but you can use an empty array `[]`):

```
      security:
        - EndpointAuthorizer: ["test/read"]
```

In the definition above, AWS will be importing the Cognito Authorizer (named `EndpointAuthorizer` in my case) as defined in `components.securitySchemes`, but you can create it with Terraform instead if you prefer (just make sure you remove it from the OpenAPI spec)

Comment: There is a subtle but *very* important difference if you use an empty array: Empty array will attempt to validate as an ID token, whereas if you have one or more values in it it will validate the bearer as an access token

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and I found it was due to how I had set the `security` property on the method.

The JSON example provided in the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-enable-cognito-user-pool.html) is:

```
"security": [
  {
    "MyUserPool": []
  }
],
```

which, in YAML, translates to:

```
security:
- MyUserPool: []
```

Note the explicit setting of the empty array. Hope this solves it for you as well.